# Check if specific key value is appeared in array 3 times

Tags: php, loops

I have an array where i want to check if start_time and end_time have the same value and start_time and end_time both happens three times than the loop should return false.

for example: In below array i have array within array, the arrays having id (4,5,6) have same start_time and end_time value, and below three arrays having id (8,9,10) have the same value.
as long as both values match it would consider as an increment, array having id (3) having the same start_time value as id (4,5,6) but it will not be considered because the end_time is different.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"start_time": "10:00",
"end_time": "11:00"
},
{
"id": 2,
"start_time": "11:00",
"end_time": "12:00"
},
{
"id": 3,
"start_time": "13:00",
"end_time": "15:00"
},
{
"id": 4,
"start_time": "13:00",
"end_time": "14:00"
},
{
"id": 5,
"start_time": "13:00",
"end_time": "14:00"
},
{
"id": 6,
"start_time": "13:00",
"end_time": "14:00"
},
{
"id": 7,
"start_time": "14:00",
"end_time": "15:00"
},
{
"id": 8,
"start_time": "17:00",
"end_time": "18:00"
},
{
"id": 9,
"start_time": "17:00",
"end_time": "18:00"
},
{
"id": 10,
"start_time": "17:00",
"end_time": "18:00"
}
]
```

Comment: Please include what attempt(s) you have made to achieve your goal.

Comment: thankyou, I have figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function checkSlotLimit($orders, $startTime, $endTime)
        {
            $counter = 0;
            foreach($orders as $order)
            {
                if( ($order->start_time === $startTime) && ($order->end_time === $endTime) )
                {
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
            return $counter;
        }

Self::checkSlotLimit($orders, $slotFrom->format('H:i'), $slotTo->format('H:i')) < 3 ? true : false;
```

Comment: could also just filter and count `return count(array_filter($orders, fn($order) => $order->start_time === $startTime && $order->end_time === $endTime));`